# dlopen on library with static member that throws exception in constructor - results in Abort

Tags: c++, unix, exception, shared-libraries, dlopen

I am trying to load a dynamic library using dlopen function. This library contains a static object, which throws an exception in its constructor. I have a "try-catch(...)" block around the dlopen call, but it doesn't catch the exception, and I just see "Abort" printed.

How am I able to catch this exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short Answer: You Can't

Thinking about it again.
The original statements holds, but you must also remember that dlopen() is a C library function. C does not support exceptions. Thus throwing an exception that crosses from C++ code to C ( Your global object back upto dlopen() ) code will also cause application termination.

See here:[Why destructor is not called on exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222175/why-destructor-is-not-called-on-exception#222358)

These are the situations under which throwing an exception will terminate the application. Your specific situation is covered by:

An exception escapes the constructor/destructor of a non local static (ie global)

Comment: And the obvious corollaries: (1) Global variables, um..ahem.. "singletons" are bad. mkay? (2) throwing an exception from a constructor of an object intended to be used as a singleton is even worse. (3) library code should never do anything that can cause the calling program to abort unless a contract has been broken (like passing an invalid pointer.

Comment: @R..: Totally agree. I don't think we need to drag singletons into this. The phrase we are looking for is `globally accessible -->mutable<-- state` whose construction can cause exceptions outside the confines of main() (or just by being loaded) are not a good idea (singletons just happen to be a subset of this larger class). Note: I suppose immutable state can also cause a problem if we want to be pedantic but usually its less worrisome.

Comment: If it's truly immutable, I wouldn't call it a "state". But in my book, any object with a constructor that modifies its contents is "mutable" even if there are no methods to later change it after construction.