# Is "extern C" code allowed to throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

In a project, we have C++ core code which loads C++ libraries dynamically. Loading those libraries works with `QLibrary::resolve`, which, however, requires the to-be-resolved functions to "be wrapped in an `extern "C"`".

Are such functions, by any standard, allowed to throw C++ classes, even though they have `extern "C"`, and can they be caught?

```
extern "C" {
CppClass1* library_function(CppClass2* parameter)
{
    throw CppClass3();
}
}
```

I read [dlopen on library with static member that throws exception in constructor - results in Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413473/dlopen-on-library-with-static-member-that-throws-exception-in-constructor-resu) , and it is very closely related, but what is requested there is said to be impossible (confirmed on my machine, Linux, gcc 13.2.1), and the code I posted above just works.

Comment: IN the end "C" code has no way of handling them. Like most technology boundaries (C++ -> C, C++ -> Python, C++ -> C#) it is best to do all transtaltions between those technologies and that includes translating error handling mechanisms. "C" has no exceptions so you probably need to make an API that can return error codes instead.

Comment: It works if you're `dlopen`ing from C++. Try making a C program instead.