# is catch guaranteed to be executed after exception is thrown?

Tags: c++, exception, stack, raii

In wikipedia [we read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization):

> Resource Acquisition Is Initialization RAII is a programming idiom
>   used in several object-oriented languages like C++, D, Ada and Vala.
>   The technique was invented by Bjarne Stroustrup to deal with resource
>   allocation and deallocation in C++. **In this language, the only code
>   that can be guaranteed to be executed after an exception is thrown are
>   the destructors of objects residing on the stack**.

I don't want to be over pedantic, whatever, but I really am not sure how to interpret this. Is this a slip of the tongue or is this correct? Aren't `catch` handlers guaranteed to be executed at least?

I know about RAII and what it is, I am focused here on this *only code that can be guaranteed to be executed (..) are destructors of objects residing on the stack*.

Comment: This quote actually contradicts what was stated in one of the recent answers on SO. According to that answer (lemme find it), if there's no catch handler for the thrown exception, the program is allowed to terminate without unwinding the stack. I.e. the destructors are NOT guaranteed to be executed in that case.

Comment: If, during stack unwinding, a dtor of an object on the stack throws, no more exception handling happens. `std::terminate()` is called right away. That would certainly prevent a `catch` from being reached.

Comment: I think AndreyT you meant also this case, however I know this, I am talking about any general code that is guaranteed to be called.

Comment: This once again demonstrates that Wikipedia is **not** an authoritative source.

Comment: While the article is not *technically* correct, I can't, off the top of my head, think of a better way to word it without an elongated explanation that completely distracts from the point of the article.  However, the fact that you are asking this question shows that, perhaps, it does need to be reworded (by a better writer than me).

Comment: It is not the most recent one, but it is about what I meant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222175/why-destructor-is-not-called-on-exception

Comment: **the only code that can be guaranteed to be executed** - this sounds so severely that caught my eye

Comment: yes, calling terminate because of no handler is known issue

Comment: How about this as a replacement for that line? **If an exception is thrown, and proper exception handling is in place, the only code that will be executed for the current scope are the destructors of objects declared in that scope.**

Comment: for me sounds more suitable/appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the quote is already wrong. When an exception is thrown and there's no matching handler for it, `terminate` can be called without unwinding the stack and calling any destructors. So, the statement that says that "destructors are *guaranteed* to be executed when an exception is thrown" is wrong.

As for `catch` handlers themselves, of course, it is only possible to execute a `catch` handler if the matching catch handler actually *exists*.

On top of that, even if the handler exists, there are other reasons that can throw a spanner in the works and prematurely terminate the processing of the exception before it reaches the `catch` handler. For example, it happens when an "unexpected" exception is thrown. If your function exception specification prohibits some specific exception type and an exception of such "prohibited" type attempts to "fly out" of that function, `unexpected` will be called immediately, instead of transferring control to the handler.

As mentioned in the comments, another typical situation is when new exception is thrown during stack unwinding triggered by a previous exception. This will result in `terminate` being called.

Comment: so this is right to say that catch is not guaranteed to be called, we may have terminate first because of exception in dctor during stuck unwinding right? I just would like someone to confirm myself

Comment: @computer: Yes, that's correct. In other words, there are some situations that a thrown exception can encounter on its way to the `catch` handler, which are considered "more-or-less catastrophic failures" by the language. If something like that happens, it is possible that the exception will never reach the handler.

Comment: "If your function exception specification prohibits some specific exception", you mean when a function throws an exception that is not listed in its dynamic-exception-specifier (i.e., in its throw specifier) right?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why I would say that Wikipedia is correct there is because if the exception causes the entire application to crash and stop execution, then it wouldn't make it down to the "catch" handler. For the most part you can guarantee that the catch clause will be found and executed.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx

Comment: In that case it is **not** guaranteed that stack objects will be destroyed. If no handler is found, the implementation calls `std::terminate()` and it is implementation-defined whether or not the stack is unwound.