When is exactly std::terminate called when an exception is not catched?
Suppose a program with some global resources in it, and in the middle of the code, an exception is thrown which is not caught and the program ends with a call to std::terminate.
If I install an std::terminate_handler, which is called by std::terminate, and my handler calls std::current_exception, I want to know if I'm guaranteed to have these global resources available at that time:

Will std::terminate be called before or after all the destructors of all global resources are destroyed? Or the call happens just after it's detected the stack frame of main is abandoned, but before all the global state is destroyed?
In which thread will std::terminate be called, in the main thread always, or in the thread that didn't catch the exception?

The point is to know what is guaranteed to exist before the call to the handler.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/222213/4165552 And I found that for C++20 the wording of 14.4.9 [except.handle] didn't change: "If no matching handler is found, the function std::terminate is called; whether or not the stack is unwound
before this call to std::terminate is implementation-defined".

@DanielLangr In that case, I'm in the control of whether to call std::abort or std::exit in the handler. The point is what is guaranteed to exist before the handler is called.

@ABu I misread the question, sorry. In that case, globals won't be destructed at all if you don't do something in your terminate handler that destructs them (such as calling std::exit).

@DanielLangr So I then assume that the compiler knows, at point where the throw happens, whether there's a catch for it all the way up to the main function? I thought the stack unwinding process worked "frame by frame", taking decisions at each step.

@ABu This might be relevant: How does C++ exception handling translate to machine code. Note that, as pointed to in the first two comments, the stack unwinding may not happen at all.

Much simpler to just catch the exception in main and return normally. I really don't understand why there are so many questions about how to deal with unhandled exceptions; just handle them. (Yes, there are situations where you can't, but there's no reason to multiply them by not catching exceptions in main).
